# How to write a batch file which gives the most recent file based on date not time?

Tags: cmd

Want to write :

- List item
- A batch file which gives the most recent file based on date.

Comment: Open a command prompt window and run `dir /?`. The output help explains the options `/O-D` (by date in reverse order from newest to oldest) and `/TW` (write date = last modification date) and others like `/B` (bare format – file/folder name only). `for /F "delims=" %%I in ('dir * /A-D /B /O-N /TW 2^>nul') do set "NewestFile=%%I" & goto HaveNewestFile` as first line in a batch file with `goto :EOF` as second line and `:HaveNewestFile` as third line and some other lines below using `"%NewestFile%"` is most likely what you need. Run also  `for /?`, `set /?` and `goto /?` in command prompt window.

Comment: Not able to get it.
See I have used this script.

for /f %%i in ('dir /b/a-d/od/t:c') do set LAST=%%i
echo The most recently created file is %LAST%

this is giving me the result but in last I want to see the ALL Files which is been made on same date.
Means
ECHO The most recently created file is" " Here is want all file which is been created on same date.

Answer (score 0):

work in two steps: a) get the newest file and b) use it's date to filter your files:

```
@echo off
REM get the newest file (to get it's date):
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /a-d /b /od /tw') do set "day=%%~ta"
REM show files, filtered by the found day:
for /f "tokens=4 delims= " %%a in ('dir /a-d^|find "%day:~0,10%"') do echo %%a
```